# OpenCv: second cvPutText not executetd

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `cvPutText` in a loop and it is working fine (printing some data connected to different contours near each contour). the thing is, when trying to use another `cvPutText` in or before the loop (for example, printing frame number in the upper left corner of the image) only the first `cvPutText` is executed and printed. the second is ignored.

the code looks like that:

```
char text[80];
```

in every loop:

```
char nam[] = "id : ";
char na[] = "  area : ";
char ka[] = "\n cNr : ";
sprintf(text,"%s%d%s%d%s%d", nam, (*obListIter)->id, ka, contNumber, na ,area);
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 1, 8);
cvPutText(cv_obj_rgb, text, cvPoint(boxPoints[4].x, boxPoints[4].y), &font, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

the other `cvPutText` looks exactly the same, only with a different font (font2), chars and text.

Can anybody help? I wasted already a couple of days because of that and I really need this feature to analyse the performance of my kalman filter and to finally finish my bachelor thesis.

Comment: I require a minimal compilable code to help you. [Read SSCCE!](http://sscce.org/) By the way what's your OpenCV version?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `cvInitFont` once, don't repeat it in a loop.

```
CvFont font1;
cvInitFont(&font1, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 1, 8);
CvFont font2;
cvInitFont(&font2, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 1, 8);
```

loop:

```
char nam[] = "id : ";
char na[] = "  area : ";
char ka[] = "\n cNr : ";
sprintf(text,"%s%d%s%d%s%d", nam, (*obListIter)->id, ka, contNumber, na ,area);
cvPutText(cv_obj_rgb, text, cvPoint(boxPoints[4].x, boxPoints[4].y), &font, cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0));
```